# How to generate a random number, then display it on screen?

Tags: android, random

Ok, im fairly new to android but i have managed to teach myself the basics, i am making an app where you press a button , and a new screen opens and it shows a randomly generated number, the only problem is i dont know how to generate and display the random number, i have been searching the web for ages and have only found little snippets of information , that dosent really make sense to me. :/

If someone could help me , or even give me just a little bit of info that should guide me in the right direction it would be great

EDIT: (for the comment below)

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Random Number : " + Math.random());
    int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
    setContentView(tv);
```

Thats the code i have , where have i gone wrong ^^^^ :/

Comment: Look closely at your variable named random. Where are you using it?

Comment: no problem, change: 

tv.setText("Random Number : " + Math.random());
int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);

to 

int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);
tv.setText("Random Number : " + random);

Comment: thankyou so much, i have finally got the hang of random numbers , you have been a great help :) :)

Comment: ok , i feel like such a fool how i keep coming back to this to ask you questions, but could you please tell me *last time i hope* how to change the size/orientation of the text that is displayed , like turn it into a string or something ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Android's documentation is excellent. Here's a hello world app:

http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

Just change

```
tv.setText("Hello, Android");
```

to

```
tv.setText("Random Number: " + Math.random());
```

and make sure to import the Math library (if you're using eclipse, hit Ctrl+Shift+O).

Comment: Thankyou so much !!!! you are a life saver :D


Just one extra question though , is there a way to set a boundary for the random number , i would like it to be between 0 and 100 :)

Comment: Sure, the normal trick is to take the number (from 0->1) and multiply it by the max then round:

int random = (int)Math.ceil(Math.random()*100);

Answer (score 5):

below code return a value in Integer:-

```
    public static int randomBox() {

    Random rand = new Random();
    int pickedNumber = rand.nextInt(100);
    return pickedNumber;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Random rand = new Random();
String randomInt = list.get(rand.nextInt(list.size()));
```

it may be help for you

Answer (score 2):

```
    Random r = new Random();

    StringBuffer temp = new StringBuffer("Random numbers:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        int i1 = r.nextInt(100 - 0) + 0;
        temp.append(String.valueOf(i1));
        temp.append(String.valueOf(" "));
    }
    return temp.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you could easily use :

```
yourVariable = Math.random();
```

Should work in Android. Gives you a number between 0 and 1. Then you give yourVariable to a TextView with the method .setText(yourVariable) for instance...

Answer (score 1):

Here is your documentation for [Random](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Random.html). Beyond that I'm not sure if you want to launch an `Activity` or update a `TextView` or what have you. However, I strongly recommend reading the documentation for [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) as well as [common tasks in android](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html) and [User Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html). These should help you understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
int number = (new Random().nextInt(100));
```

a random number will be assigned to variable number, each time it is used

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to devloper your own algorithms to generate random number, pick any algo and implement in any language of preference. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators

Answer (score 0):

Different way, but simple:)

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    final int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);

    Random r = new Random();
    final int n = r.nextInt(80 - 65) + 65;

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+ n + seconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Random r = new Random();
        rendomNumber = r.nextInt(80- 65) + 65;
        System.out.print(""+rendomNumber )
```