# How do I write a random quote generator in Java for Android?

Tags: android, string, random

I am very new to Java for Android, and am basically just a noob trying to make a few basic apps for a HTC phone. So far, mainly by copying code, I've written apps that will write "Hello, World", print a random number and display a picture, and these have worked nicely on my phone.

I would now like to combine what I've done and write an app that will generate a random quote from a specified list and print it on the screen. A refresh button would be nice, too.

I looked at these links first as a starting point: 
[Forrst](http://forrst.com/posts/Java_Get_random_quote_from_list_of_quotes-OWt)
[Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2405411/how-to-generate-a-random-number-then-display-it-on-screen)

However, I think I'm going in circles now by trying to combine the two. I started off by making an array of the quotes, generating a random number and assigning it to the quote, then trying to get the tv.setText method to write it.

Any help gratefully received! Thank you!

This is what I have so far:

```
package com.Me;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Random;

public class QuoteActivity extends Activity {

int numQuotes = 10;
String[] quotes = new String[numQuotes] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
String randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * numQuotes)];

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //Make a new text view passing Activity object
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    //Set a text into view

    tv.setText(randomQuote);
    //set the view into activity view container
    setContentView(tv);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Ok, some basic stuff first: you're not assigning numbers to the quotes, you're using the random number to index the quotes array. With that said, something like this would do the trick:

```
String[] quotes = new String[] {"q1", "q2", "q3"};
String randomQuote = quotes[(int) (Math.random() * quotes.length)];
```

Please note that you cannot both set the size of an array and initialize it at the same time. I.e. either you do like above, or you do something like:

```
int numQuotes = 3;
String[] quotes = new String[numQuotes];
quotes[0] = "q1";
quotes[1] = "q2";
quotes[2] = "q3";
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of errors in your code:

- You init an array either by

`String[] quotes = new String[]{"1", "2", "3"};`

or

```
String[] quotes = new String[3];
quotes[0] = "1";
quotes[1] = "2";
quotes[2] = "3";
```

- The Math.floor() and Math.random() return double, and you should access array elements with ints. You should cast to int. You don't actually need floor() because random() returns positive value.
- You will get an exception if you try to access an array element that is not there. If you have array with 3 elements and math.random()*10 gives you 4 - you will crash.

I suggest:

```
int randomElemenetIndex = (int) (Math.random() * 10) % 3; //This way you will have 0, 1 or 2
...
tv.setText(quotes[randomElementIndex]);
```

Comment: This is brilliant, thank you. This is the one I went with in the end, and it's working perfectly. There are a number of apps I can make with this basis. Clearly I need to go back to basics with my Java anyway, but in the meantime this is great :)

Comment: Glad to help :)
Btw the new Java 7 states:
As of Java 7, we should never again use Math.random(). Java 7 gives us a new ThreadLocalRandom class that has one unshared Random instance per thread.
So if you use Java 7 you should consider migrating to this.